# Solr 4.4 with Tomcat 8.0.0 Windows

Tags: windows, solr4, tomcat8

I have a little problem with Solr. I want to start the application in the tomcat environment. I have tried different tutorials but nothing works fine.

I have used the Tomcat Web Application Manager to open the solr.war file. In my oppinion it is the same as copying the war file into the webapp folder of the tomcat directory. The application was successfull loaded! When i go to localhost:8080/solr/, i get some errors.

In my opinion a path is missing in some config files, but i don't know which one.

```
HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: 
Could not load config for solrconfig.xml,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load config for 
solrconfig.xml at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:860) at 
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:251) at 
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:158) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.jav
a:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:223) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) at 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:75) at 
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934) at 

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90) at 
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:494) at 
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009) 
at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:
632) at 
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtoco
l.java:281) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2248) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2237) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
Could not load config for solrconfig.xml at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:592) at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:657) at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:364) at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:356) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) at 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ... 3 more Caused by: 
java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'C:solrsolr-
multicore\collection1\conf/', cwd=D:\Suchmaschine\Tomcat\Software\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC1-
windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC1\bin at 
org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:322) at 
org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:287) at 
org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:116) at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>
(Config.java:86) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:120) at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:589) ... 11 more 
,code=500}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/setting-up-solr-with-apache-tomcat-be.html

Has a good guide to setting it up with tomcat 7 which doesnt change for tomcat 8

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue when deploying solr 4.9.1 on Tomcat 7 on Windows. The issue was tomcat failing to identify the correct solr home directory. Fixed this by adding the following snippet in catalina.bat

set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsolr.solr.home="

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the solr.home ?

in catalina.sh (/usr/share/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh):

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dsolr.solr.home=/etc/tomcat6/solr -Djava.awt.headless=true -server -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```